# Why is 2-Dimensional Electron Gas (2DEG) materials interesting?

Tags: condensed-matter

I noticed lots of research publications about 2DEG materials, e.g. AlGaN/GaN hetero-structures. I want to know what is interesting here. Is there a fundamental physics or technological potential?

Answer (score 4):

Both! The fundamental physics comes from the fact that these were the first systems (in the pre-graphene era) to really exhibit two-dimensionality! In two dimensions, physics can be fundamentally different which is exhibited by the integer and fractional quantum hall effects, the quantum spin hall effect and Kosterlitz-Thouless-type phase transitions just to name a few. A good reference about 2D phenomena is Thouless' article in the volume "The New Physics" ed. Paul Davies.

From a technological viewpoint,2D phenomena are also extremely important. In fact, the GMR effect uses magnetic thin films to store data in most hard drives. Right now, I think that applications of 2DEGs in heterostructures are pretty limited but do hold potential for future applications.

Answer (score 2):

Yes 2DEG offers some fundamental physics by eliminating one spatial degree of freedom. Of most important physics the quantum Hall measurement comes to mind.

From a technological perspective, the [bandgap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_gap) engineering of [heterostructure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterojunction) devices allows the formation of 2DEG, i.e. a high concentration of charge without recourse to mechanisms such as doping, which would otherwise substantially reduce carrier mobility because of scattering with dopants. Therefore a much much higher mobilities can be achieved which would ultimately translate to faster and better devices. It is like having the best of two worlds: the high mobility of undoped semiconductor and high carrier concentration of a doped one.